# Transformation and CSG Operations on grid in OpenVDB

Tags: c++, tree, csg, openvdb

OpenVDB seems really amazing, and the addressing of the nodes is really smart. There are some operations that I don't understand, in particular CSG operations. This is a example code. It takes as input two arguments:

- a vdb input file with only one grid, representing a level set created starting from a triangular mesh,
- a vdb output that stores the results of the operations.

The algorithm should take the input,

1. creates a deepCopy in gridA
2. creates a deepCopy in gridB
3. rotates gridB along Y axiz of M_PI/4.0f
4. performs the csgUnion between gridA and gridB
5. saves all grids in a vdb output file.

I'm trying to use VDB grids as data container in place of classicaloctree algorithm, for physical simulations that needs an high level of detail in collisions.

I understand the concept of transformation between world coordinates and grid coordinates, what I cannot understand is how to perform a transformation of data inside the tree, like translate or rotate the level-sets, like a rigid object. In the example, I think I'm only changing the transformation between world and lattice.

This is the result (the same for level-set and volume):[image: gridA should be the original loaded grid]Initial Grid[image: gridB is the grid rotated of 45 degrees, and in fact it is]Trasformed grid, it seems that the rotation is performed...[image: result grid with the union... but no luck...]no final result?

Do you have suggestions?

Attached: one example and a link to the **LINK REMOVED** that I'm using (sorry, it is 133MB...)

```
#include <cmath>
#include "openvdb/openvdb.h"
#include "openvdb/util/Util.h"
#include "openvdb/io/Stream.h"
#include "openvdb/tools/Composite.h"

using namespace openvdb;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  openvdb::initialize();

  openvdb::io::File file(argv[1]);
  file.open();

  GridBase::Ptr baseGrid;
  for (openvdb::io::File::NameIterator nameIter = file.beginName(); 
       nameIter != file.endName(); ++nameIter) 
       { baseGrid = file.readGrid(nameIter.gridName()); }

  file.close();
  FloatGrid::Ptr gridA = gridPtrCast<FloatGrid>(baseGrid);
  FloatGrid::Ptr gridB = gridA->deepCopy();
  FloatGrid::Ptr result = gridA ->deepCopy();

  gridB->transform().postRotate(M_PI/4.0f, math::Y_AXIS);

  tools::csgUnion(*result, *gridB);

  openvdb::io::File file_out(argv[2]);
  GridPtrVec grids;

  grids.push_back(gridA);
  grids.push_back(gridB);
  grids.push_back(result);

  file_out.write(grids);
  file_out.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please change your title into a question. Your real question is buried. It seems to be something like, "How do I perform a transformation of data inside an OpenVDB tree?"

Comment: I don't know if I'm making the error during transformation or in CSG operation. Anyway, I've changed the title to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my answer, thanks to VDB support in OpenVDB forum, is:

1. Execute a simple *metadata* copy of the initial grid
2. Execute the transformation (like the rotation in my code)
3. **reinterpolate data form the initial grid in the new transformed grid**, using `tools::resampleToMatch`, choosing one of the interpolator (in my case `tools::BoxSample`) available.
4. continue with csg operations

FYI, there is an **extreme difference** in execution time 
 using optimization flag `-O3` (400% time reduction).

```
#include "openvdb/io/Stream.h"
#include "openvdb/openvdb.h"
#include "openvdb/tools/Composite.h"
#include "openvdb/tools/GridTransformer.h"
#include "openvdb/tools/Interpolation.h"
#include "openvdb/util/Util.h"

#include <cmath>

using namespace openvdb;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  openvdb::initialize();

  openvdb::io::File file(argv[1]);
  file.open();

  GridBase::Ptr baseGrid;
  for (openvdb::io::File::NameIterator nameIter = file.beginName();
       nameIter != file.endName(); ++nameIter) {
    baseGrid = file.readGrid(nameIter.gridName());
  }

  file.close();
  FloatGrid::Ptr gridA = gridPtrCast<FloatGrid>(baseGrid);
  FloatGrid::Ptr gridB = gridA->copy(CP_NEW);
  gridB->setTransform(gridA->transform().copy());
  gridB->transform().postRotate(M_PI / 4.0f, math::Y_AXIS);

  tools::resampleToMatch<tools::BoxSampler>(*gridA, *gridB);

  FloatGrid::Ptr result = gridA->deepCopy();
  FloatGrid::Ptr gridB2 = gridB->deepCopy();

  tools::csgUnion(*result, *gridB);

  openvdb::io::File file_out(argv[2]);
  GridPtrVec grids;

  grids.push_back(gridA);
  grids.push_back(gridB2);
  grids.push_back(result);

  file_out.write(grids);
  file_out.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Reference: [OpenVDB Forum](http://www.openvdb.org/forum/?place=msg%2Fopenvdb-forum%2FFSD_qwRjXfU%2FsS5OaesEBAAJ)